# Randomize WooCommerce "Shop By Category"

Tags: php, wordpress, random, woocommerce, hook

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce webstore. I have the shop by category option selected and the front page currently shows the first 3 categories.

Instead of the first three categories I would like it to show 3 random categories.

I was able to add a custom function to my function.php (code below) to increase the number of categories listed (to 10) but I'm not able to have the categories show up in a random order.

```
add_filter('storefront_product_categories_shortcode_args','custom_storefront_category_per_page' );

// Category Products
function custom_storefront_category_per_page( $args ) {
    $args['number'] = 10;
    return $args;
}
```

I have tired setting $args['orderby'] = "rand"; with no luck. Im guessing that only works for products. What function should I be changing to have the "Shop By Category" section on the front page list 3 random categories instead of 3 categories in AESC or DESC order?

Answer (score 1):

if orderby = rand is not working for your case please try below technique.

-- first you need to get the random category for  products to display in the page.

-- then pass it to the shortcode.

```
$categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );

$all_cat = array();

foreach( $categories as $cat ){

$all_cat[] = $cat->name; 

}

$random_cat // get and create random category with comma seperated. and pass it to the shortcode.
 $randomCat = "tshirt, shirt";

echo do_shortcode('[products limit="8" columns="4" category="$randomCat" cat_operator="AND"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Would this go in the child theme's function.php? and is the $random_cat in your example a function or a list?

Comment: hello,

you got all the category name in $all_cat array then you need to choose a randomized category and create a string of category with comma seperated like as $randomCat and pass it to the shortcode.